# Plot Line Types in R

Tags: r, plot

Update:

This has been confirmed as a current bug on Apple OS as of Feb 28, 2022.

---

Update:

Below is my sessionInfo. I have tried to restart my RStudio and tried dev.off(), but neither works. I am still getting the odd dashed line.

I have tried the codes on R (not RStudio) and the dashed line is still wrong.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.2.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2 tools_4.1.2
```

---

The following codes will produce Plot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kanse.png).

```
zeta.ppt <- function(v){
  ppt=function(i){
    result <- numeric(length(i))
    for (j in i){
      if (j < 11) {result[j] <- (11-j)/110}
      else {result[j] <- 3/pi^2/(j-10)^2}
    }
    result
  }
  p <- ppt(1:10000)
  printout <- numeric(length(v))
  for (k in 1:length(v)) {
    printout[k] <- sum(p*(1-p)^v[k])
  }
  printout
}
zeta.sept <- function(v){
  sept=function(i){
    result <- numeric(length(i))
    for (j in i){
      if (j < 11) {result[j] <- (11-j)/110}
      else {result[j] <- 0.5/1.670407*exp(-sqrt(j-10))}
    }
    result
  }
  p <- sept(1:10000)
  printout <- numeric(length(v))
  for (k in 1:length(v)) {
    printout[k] <- sum(p*(1-p)^v[k])
  }
  printout
}
tau.ppt <- function(v){
  v*zeta.ppt(v)
}
tau.sept <- function(v){
  v*zeta.sept(v)
}
plot(log(tau.ppt(1:20000))~log(1:20000), xlim = c(0,10), ylim=c(0, 5), axes = F, ylab = "", xlab = "", type = "l")
lines(log(tau.sept(1:20000))~log(1:20000), lty = 2, type = "l")
box()
```

[image: Plot 1]

If you look at the dashed line, it is not evenly separated in its right-hand side portion. How can I make it an evenly spaced dashed line like Plot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXiQZ.png)?

[image: Plot 2]

Thanks!

Comment: I have plot it in RStudio and the line is separated. What software do you use?

Comment: Rstudio. Can you paste your plot here? Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped/solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have updated with my sessionInfo. I am still unable to get a good dashed line. I did try dev.off() as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have plot it in RStudio and the line is separated (Author asked to show my image). You could also try to run `dev.off()` before you plot your image.

My RStudio version:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
```

[image]

Comment: That’s really weird to me. I will send you my session info when I get back to the computer. Thanks

Comment: @J.Z. if you haven't, I'd also try running it in a fresh R session, and see if it persists when you open plot zoom or save it to disk.

Comment: Same for me perfectly separated.  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Comment: @zephryl Thanks for the tips. I tried with a fresh R session, on two different Mac (one intel chip, one M1 chip - sorry I only have Mac). I tried zoom, I tried reshaping it in the zoom window in RStudio, and I tried saving it. Unfortunately, none works.

Comment: @J.Z. If our tips helped you, votes up dont cost money.